# How can I setup a testing environment for testing with selenium and phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to setup environment for headless testing using Selenium and PhantomJS.

#### Setting UP phantomjs:

I have made a folder `c:/phantomjs` and put all the phantomjs script files there (after downloading).

Then I created a folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS`

Now I installed nodeJS in my system.

Then I traversed to the `C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS` in the command prompt and installed phantomJS like this:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS>npm install -g phantomjs`

The image states a different location. Thats because it was taken from my colleague's computer. We both are working on same installation, and he sent me the image for reference. That's why its different with my folder location, but the location I stated, it is the one I worked on.

[image]

Now on typing phantomjs on command prompt, when we are typing

`C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS>phantomjs`

`phantom>`

#### Setting Up Selenium-Webdriver

I traversed to `C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS` in the command prompt and installed selenium webdriver like this:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS>npm install selenium-webdriver`

[image]

After installation, the folder structure is like this:
[image]

Now I have a test-script `test.js` which is like this:

```
describe('Test example.com', function(){
    before(function(done) {
        client.init().url('http://google.com', done);
    });

    describe('Check homepage', function(){
        it('should see the correct title', function(done) {
            client.getTitle(function(err, title){
                expect(title).to.have.string('Example Domain');
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should see the body', function(done) {
            client.getText('p', function(err, p){
                expect(p).to.have.string(
                    'for illustrative examples in documents.'
                );
                done();
            })
        });
    });

    after(function(done) {
        client.end();
        done();
    });
});
```

The problem is, where should I put the above script, and how shall I run it?
I just don't need to run using the phantomjs only, I need to test with both phantomjs and selenium.

Comment: Well the tning you stated, it means running js file with phantomjs only... i need to test by selenium and phantomjs both @TZHX

Comment: Why the constant downvote? Is the question such an ridiculous one for a beginner?

Comment: Looks like a meta effect occuring

Comment: Meta effect doesn't mean that people will be downvoting it without any reason. I would like to know what's the problem with this question? Grammatical mistakes, or capital letter issue, or punctuation inconsistency, or technical confusion or anything else like bad impression?

Comment: Meta effect *can* mean that people downvoting with no reason - there is no way of knowing for sure unless they comment (which they are not obliged to).

Comment: OK, so basically it means that I should not post anything on meta, as it might displease someone and he/she can give downvote without providing any explanation. Thanks for letting me know. I thought that meta is for helping people out. But it seems posting on meta means inviting downvotes.

Comment: That's is 100% up to you.

Answer (score 6):

This solution is coming from this pretty neat tutorial on how to setup testing with selenium and phantomjs: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs--net-30545

Here is some of the tutorial below:

### Combining Everything

Now that we have all the pieces, we have to put everything together.

Remember: before running any tests, you have to run Selenium Server:

1
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
Selenium will run PhantomJS internally; you don't have to worry about that.

Now, we need to connect to Selenium from our JavaScript. Here's a sample snippet, which will initiate a connection to Selenium and have a ready object to control our Selenium instance:

```
// Use webdriverjs to create a Selenium Client
var client = require('webdriverjs').remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        // You may choose other browsers
        // http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
        browserName: 'phantomjs'
    },
    // webdriverjs has a lot of output which is generally useless
    // However, if anything goes wrong, remove this to see more details
    logLevel: 'silent'
});

client.init();
Now, we can describe our tests and use the client variable to control the browser.
```

A full reference for the webdriverjs API is available in the documentation, but here's a short example:

```
client.url('http://example.com/')
client.getTitle(function(title){
    console.log('Title is', title);
});
client.setValue('#field', 'value');
client.submitForm();
client.end();
```

Let's use the Mocha and Chai syntax to describe a test; we'll test some properties of the example.com web page:

```
describe('Test example.com', function(){
    before(function(done) {
        client.init().url('http://example.com', done);
    });

    describe('Check homepage', function(){
        it('should see the correct title', function(done) {
            client.getTitle(function(title){
                expect(title).to.have.string('Example Domain');
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should see the body', function(done) {
            client.getText('p', function(p){
                expect(title).to.have.string(
                    'for illustrative examples in documents.'
                );
                done();
            })
        });
    });

    after(function(done) {
        client.end();
        done();
    });
});
```

You might want to share one client initialization over many test files. Create a small Node module to initialize and import it into every test file:

client.js:

```
exports.client = require('webdriverjs').remote({
    // Settings
};
```

test.js:

```
var client = require('./client').client;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
 
// Perform tests
```

### EDIT based on the question in the comments:

Here is how to install the selenium server, and yes you need to do it.

**Selenium**

Download Selenium Server. It is distributed as a single jar file, which you run simply:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
```

As soon as you execute this command, it boots up a server to which your testing code will connect later on. Please note that you will need to run Selenium Server every time that you run your tests.

Comment: Hello @Maxime, but do I need to install selenium server, or the selenium webdriver will do?

Comment: I need some discussions here, would you mind for a discussion?

Comment: Extended discussions are discouraged here

Comment: So, how can i clear out my problem? I need some explanation. @santiago

Comment: Regardless, this is not a discussion forum, nor a tutorial site

Comment: Actually I am stuck in a situation. :(

Comment: You could invite the answerer to a chatroom (not sure how), but it is up to them if they choose to participate

Comment: Read my edit. I've added the selenium server installation.

Comment: Well, can't we just setup the environment with the node.js alone. I mean by not using the python environment?